# Haskell - Elegant code for detecting if number is in range

Tags: haskell, code-cleanup

I'm writing my homework and I found piece of code I don't think is elegant enought..

Exactly :

```
if n >= min && n <= max 
    then ...
    else ...
```

I want to ask if there is any more elegant way to write this code for checking if number is in range (min, max)

Comment: When you test if a value is inside a range there is a way to format it to make it a little clearer: `min <= n && n <= max`. This formatting indicates a little bit better that `n` lies between `min` and `max`.

Comment: Yeah right.. this is the best i can do I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The answer below is just a cute trick, I wouldn't actually recommend using it!)

With some tricks, you can actually make operators that act kind of like ternary operators, so you get nice code to say "in range". Here's the operators in question:

```hs
infixr 4 <=!
infixr 4 !<=
(<=!) :: Ord a => a -> (Bool,a) -> Bool
lb <=! (iub, x) = iub && (lb <= x)

(!<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> (Bool,a)
x !<= ub = (x <= ub, x)
```

You can use them like this:

```hs
>>> 1 <=! 3 !<= 5
True
>>> 1 <=! 0 !<= 5
False
```

You can even add strict relation operators:

```hs
infixr 4 <!
infixr 4 !<
(<!) :: Ord a => a -> (Bool,a) -> Bool
lb <! (iub, x) = iub && (lb < x)

(!<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> (Bool,a)
x !< ub = (x < ub, x)
```

And mix and match:

```hs
>>> 0 <=! 2 !<= 2
True
>>> 0 <=! 2 !<  2
False
```

Comment: Really interesting approach. Definitely will try to code some 'ternary' operations with this method

Answer (score 3):

I think this is as short as it can get out of the box. If this problem appears too often in your code to become annoying, you can extract it to a function, as suggested [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Comparison_chain):

```
(<?) :: Ord a => a -> (a,a) -> Bool
(<?) x (min, max) = x >= min && x <= max
```

And then use as:

```
if x <? (min, max) 
    then ... 
    else...
```

**Update**: it turns out, there's also a function [`inRange`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#v:inRange) in the base package.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking if there is some function like inRange in Prelude.

Comment: Oh, actually, not in Prelude, but [there is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html#v:inRange)!

Comment: What a pity that we can use in homework only Prelude and Data.List ... But thank you for tip

Comment: `inRange` does require a stronger constraint on `a`, though.

Comment: And there is no instance for `Double`, for example